# Please tell me how to write the code short

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

I am novice about programming.

As shown below, I have plenty of buttons on UIView.

In this case, what kind of method can be used to express with short code?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonD: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonE: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonF: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonG: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonH: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonI: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonJ: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var alphaView: UIView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonA, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonB, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonC, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonD, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonE, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonF, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonG, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonH, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonI, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonJ, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
   }
}
```

Comment: If you add a view in Interface Builder, you don't need to add it to the view with code. You can also order them in Interface Builder. Unless you're doing something else with your buttons, all of that code is unnecessary.

Comment: Use XIB or Storyboard and you can avid the `insertSubView` part at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an outlet collection and connect all your buttons to it. Then iterate it like this.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!{
    didSet{
        for button in self.buttons{
            self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.alphaView)
        }
    }
}
```